# react-popper: Should I use one <Manager> component or many on the same page?

Tags: reactjs, popper.js

Should I have one `<Manager>` component at the root of my whole project or is it better to have one `<Manager>` for each place I want to pop up content? So for example, one wrapped around every drop down menu and every hover tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely wrap every reference element, as you can see that's done in the official repo's demo:

https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper/blob/master/demo/index.js#L61

If you look at the source code, you'll see that the Reference component uses a Context Consumer to save a reference to the parent Manager component.